# How do I search my Favourites within IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

In an older version of IE I could do a search of a Favourite I was looking for; how do I search for specific Favourites in IE 9?

Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method is to navigate to the favorites folder in your user account folder, then use explorer search.

C:\Users\ [your user name] \Favorites

Comment: No other way within the browser?

Comment: Not that I have ever found.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Favorites]

You should see favorites Star on the upper right hand corner of IE 9.